# Download entire album from Google+?

Tags: software-rec, download, pictures, google-plus

Is there any software that can download all the full-size pictures of a publicly-shared Google+ album?

Comment: Close-voters: I'm looking for a *program* (or a browser extension). Is that really a WebApps.StackExchange question?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: Try this tool:
http://code.google.com/p/gpalbum/

Comment: @vurdalakov: That's pretty darn amazing, thanks for making it!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by @vurdalakov

With this tool:
http://code.google.com/p/gpalbum/
and an implementation of wget it is possible to have the files in seconds.

```
Download, unzip, and run the gpalbum program    
Visit the album and copy the url out of the address bar    
Paste the url into gpalbum    
Click "Get Image URLs"    
Click "Copy Image URLs to clipboard    
Paste URLs into any text editor    
replace all "https" with "wget https"    
Save it as a batch file    
Run
```

All the images are now downloaded locally, I have been looking for this for a while, just tried it and it is fantastic.

FYI Each line looks something like this

```
wget https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/FULLIMAGEPATH.jpg
```

The specific version used for testing was 1.00 (update: 1.03 also tested).

Comment: A bit codey, but not too bad. I like this solution.

Comment: Truth is it belonged to vurdalakov and I was just going to add details but it got deleted while I was editing.  I've tried it on a couple of publicly posted albums and it is really sweet and I'm guessing it will run via Wine on Linux.  Once everything is in place it is just clicking the right buttons.

Comment: Yea, his answer was deleted because it was just a link with no description or instructions, which isn't a very helpful answer even if it is technically correct. Your answer provides the necessary details.

Comment: I wish @vurdalakov could post this as an answer so we could vote it up... the tool is pretty darn useful!

Comment: @Dennis this tool also works with Linux and Mono! Instructions for Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install mono-runtime libmono-winforms2.0-cil libmono-microsoft8.0-cil` and then run the tool with `mono gpalbum.exe ` . Unfortunately this tool did not help me because I tried to download a private album (with Authkey) which is not possible right now :(

Comment: @therealmarv I actually tried that and couldn't get it to work on public albums either.  I didn't try very hard because I was just researching the answer.  If you do actually run it successfully some time I'd love to hear about it (versions and such).

Comment: @Dennis forget my answer about Linux. The program is running without error messages but when I try to download any album I get following error: `Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication  or decryption has failed.): SendFailure` :( It seems mono has some errors with SSL handling. See here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1841740

Comment: seems overkill to me. see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following commands in a bash shell (e.g. a Linux terminal):

(copy&paste the album URL to the end of the first one)

```
wget -O album.html  https://plus.google.com/photos/XXX/albums/YYY?authkey=ZZZ
grep '"https://lh..googleusercontent.com/.*",\[' album.html | sed 's%,"\(https://lh..googleusercontent.com/.*\)",\[".*%\1=w0-h0%' >images.txt
wget -i images.txt --content-disposition
```

There you get them all, in full size (but no EXIF data)! This even works for private albums (visibility: *‘anyone with the link’*).

Comment: Works fine except that some garbage names must be removed (I did this with `grep -v script | grep -v '0,0\.0'`). Note that in case the album can only be accessed when you are logged in, then the first command will not work, but you can just download the album page with your browser (Save As) and do the rest directly on it. There seems to be no access control on the photos themselves.

Comment: @a3nm thx for the comment, feel free to edit the answer to make it better :)

Comment: This answer no longer works with the newer Google+ albums. It only saves an "album.html" file and no images.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version of Picasa, then start Picasa, and check the top right side of the window to make sure you are logged into Google Plus.

Then Click

File, Import from Google+ Photos

Answer (score 1):

Had to do this today since they are closing Google Plus in a couple of days and a deceased friend of mine had shared my birthday photos with me so I wanted to download a copy before they shut down. What I ended up doing was look at the album source on:
`https://get.google.com/albumarchive/<user_id>` (I had to get the `user_id` from their Google Plus page: `https://plus.google.com/<user_id>/`

At the bottom of the source file for each album look for `"album_id", [list]`, where album_id is in the URL for each album in the `albumarchive` page.

You can then use a script to read the `[list]` as json and iterate through it. For example I wrote a Python script to download all the images:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as jf:
    images = json.load(jf)
for image in images:
    url = image[1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '<path_to_save_directory>' + image[11])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Picasa should allow you to download full albums to your computer.

Here's the how-to from Google support:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=6847c29152910e21&hl=en

This apparently only works for albums which are shared to Google+ from Picasaweb. Albums only in Google+ are not capable of being downloaded in bulk.

Comment: I've already seen [the instructions](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=39513) but those are for Picasa, not Google+. They only work for older accounts that aren't integrated with Google+.

Comment: Then the most recent answer I've seen show that Google+-only albums are not capable of being downloaded in a single package.

Comment: Obviously not with built-in functionality. That's why I'm asking if there's any program that can do it.

Comment: Based on all albums my family shares (so purely anecdotal, I may be wrong, but this is our experience), Picasa still serves the images to G+ so there are Picasa albums that I have downloaded using Picasa and the tricks found at http://techmeasy.blogspot.com/2011/09/download-images-in-original-size-from.html    the key for me was getting the address and using the ?noredirect=1 found in the post.  But if I'm on a computer without Picasa I use the wget trick in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm like so much new wallpapers shared on Google Plus but I don't like to download them manually so today I'm just create a bash script to download complete Google Plus Album for me ;-)

**Download Script:** [Google Plus Album Downloder](https://github.com/MiteshShah/GPlusAlbumDownloader)

[How to use Video Tutorials:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWbe7x3hbYk)